# How to determine the AUCTex TeX engine?

Tags: auctex

How can I find out which TeX engine my AUCTeX uses? How can I change the TeX engine my AUCTeX uses (specifically, (a) to LuaTeX, (b) to XeTeX)? Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21212/21685) post, I tried to inspect the value of the variable `TeX-engine`, however this variable isn't defined in my environment, even though AUCTeX works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This variable is not defined (or set) until AUCTeX is loaded. On your system, it seems to be deferred until it is first needed ("autoloaded" in emacs slang).

More precisely:

- you start emacs, some initialization happens during which emacs notes that `LaTeX-mode` is defined in some `.el` file in the AUCTeX package;
- if you try to inspect `TeX-engine` at this point, the variable has never been defined;
- if you now open a `.tex` file, emacs turns on `LaTeX-mode`, which is not loaded yet. So emacs loads the AUCTeX package, and now `TeX-engine` is defined;
- at this point, you can inspect `TeX-engine` from any buffer of the emacs session (it will have a default value in all buffers, and a buffer-local value in AUCTeX buffers).

For your second question, you can use the command `TeX-engine-set`, which will apply the setting to the current buffer. To apply the setting to the default value (for all buffers), set the variable through the customize interface.